# How can I make unite-vim prioritize folders in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, unite.vim

When I use [Unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim) to grep through my job's rails app, I usually get results in test/ and db/ before app/.  This means a lot of scrolling before I get to anything useful.

I see that unite lets you pick a predefined sorter for customizing the order of results.  I also see that it lets you create your own sorter function.  What I don't see is documentation for how to do this.  Any pointers for how I can make this happen?  Any other ideas besides the sorter?  (For a while I was thinking of changing the grep/ag option I was using, but that seemed ugly.)